# Any ready-to-use Dashboard/Admin Bootstrap templates for Aurelia?

Tags: templates, twitter-bootstrap-3, aurelia, dashboard

There are plenty of such templates for Angular or React? 
Here is [an example](https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/materialpro-admin-angular-cli-starter-WB0RN719L)

Is there something similar for Aurelia?

Comment: This is a bit broad - if you're looking for bootstrap templates, they don't really need to be Aurelia specific. What about bootstrap and Aurelia are you trying to combine that wouldn't be solved by [this](https://colorlib.com/polygon/gentelella/index.html) for example? Do you want something you can download/clone that already has bootstrap mixed with Aurelia?